# Handlebars debug missing {{property}} of model

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to see in the `console` some kind of output if a template doesn't get all {{properties}} (for debugging)

e.g. If a template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="demo">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <p>{{desc}}</p>
</script>
```

is called with a model

```
{
  name:"Max",
}
```

there should be an output like `console.warn`

```
Template "demo" could not find property "desc"
```

Is there any helper, callback, ... that is called every time a Handlebars expression like {{property}} is called?

Comment: Sadly, there is no out of the box solution to this day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you like with javascript. But do it carefully. :)

There are many way to achieve your goal depending on what you really need and how many time you can spend on hacking ember/handlebars/ember-data packages.

First and easiest variant is to override `render` method of SimpleHandlebarsView/_HandlebarsBoundView, which displays simple binded values (there are few other views: for `@each`, `with`, etc). This is simple sequence: override method, call an old method, check the result of getting value for rendering, `console.warn` if `result === undefined`. You can't get template name inside that method, but you can get parent view for rendered value. So, I suggest to turn on LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS to easily match views with templates.

Example of console logs:

```
Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember226> Object {fullName: "view:application"} 
Rendering index with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember251> Object {fullName: "view:index"}
Rendering <(subclass of Ember.View):ember251> , property is undefined: model.undefined
```

[JSBin with example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kewiyu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Another way is to override handlebarsGet method from ember-handlebars-ext package: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L75.

Third, if you need to catch accessing to undefined properties of `Ember.Objects`, you can override [unknownProperty](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unknownProperty) method for those objects.

If you need to check a rendered data quickly, you can use [`{{log model}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_handlebars-debugging-helpers) method in Handlebar's template.

You can get deeper into patching and rewriting core of Ember, of course. But I advise not to rely much on inner structure of libraries. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like a reasonable effort for debugging. I was aware of the {{debug}} and {{log model}} helpers, but they require changing the templates, which I would prefere not to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

No, they use `Ember.get(context, propertyName)`  There is no metadata returned saying the property is defined vs undefined.